# .Net Secure Token Service (STS) issuing different Tokens based on the Realm

Tags: .net, wif, windows-identity

I have implemented a .Net STS website and everything is working fine. The token is populated with Claims of type Role, and these are used to control what the user has access to in the application.

A new requirement is that there needs to be a second application, which is a subset of the functionality in primary application, which offers a read only view of certain parts of the system. It should also use Active Directory authentication so that the user does not need to login with a username & password combination.

I have extended the STS website to authenticate the user using Active Directory and issue a token containing a single claim/role which enforces this read-only view.

This works fine, however my problem is that it is likely that users will be using both applications at the same time. When this happens, the token is populated with more roles and users in the read-only application can access more than they should.

The only way I can see around this problem is to configure the secondary/read-only application to use a different secure token.

My question is whether the .Net STS can do this, and if so, how?

Many thanks,
John

Comment: Which STS are you using? If you're wrapping the WIF SecurityTokenService, then yes, you can do this. Use a different scope for the two different relying parties.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Roger. I'm not sure if it's WIF. It's the STS website you get when you right click on a project/web application in Visual Studio and click "Add STS Website". There's no scope settings in the web.config of the RP's from what I can see.

Comment: That's the development STS? That shouldn't really be used in production. Look at http://thinktecture.github.com/ for a production-ready STS.

Comment: Thanks for the link. We've customised the boilerplate to suit our needs and it works well, with the exception of the issue outlined above. Unless there are any gaping holes in the security I don't see why it can't be used in Production...?

Answer (score 0):

You'd might want to have a look at [ADFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx) if you need an STS with AD authentication, it's pretty easy to set up and configure. The latest version is [AD FS 2.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/ee476597.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The boilerplate Sts that you add with visual studio is NOT for production use, if you check the Microsoft documentation note that it says the sane thing, the list if things that the dev template too many to list. Look at adfs 2.0 and you will begin to see the additional feature sets that can be leveraged to implement a claims based system.